# How to capture group matching in if clause and use one group if matches

Tags: bash

There are some servers with the following hostnames:

```
hostname1
Hostname2
hostname3
hostname10
Hostname21
hostname120
```

```
if [[ "$(hostname)" =~ ^[Hh]ostname([0-9]{1,3})$ ]]
then
    echo "This is hostname$1"
else
    echo "$(hostname)"
fi
```

Expected output (all hostnames with capital H are now small h):

```
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
hostname10
hostname21
hostname120
```

Comment: You show the comparison, but not how you get the input into your program. Please provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I intend to run this on each server and if hostname matches that, then it'll do something. Do you need sample data for the `if` clause?

Comment: See `man bash`, section `Parameter Expansion`, sous-section `Case modification`: `${hostname,}` converts the first character to lowercase; `${hostname,,}` converts the whole value to lowercase.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet intention is not to convert to lowercase. It's to use a group in matching regex.

Comment: So there are other differences between your input and your output than letter case? If no, the intention is clearly to convert to lowercase. If yes please edit your question and provide a [Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as already asked in other comments.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes, there are other differences, but I tried to make question simple.

Comment: Simplifying your question is an excellent idea. But not up to the point where it does not address the real issue any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BASH_REMATCH:

```
if [[ "$(hostname)" =~ ^[Hh]ostname([0-9]{1,3})$ ]]
then
    echo "This is hostname${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    echo "$(hostname)"
fi
```